# Cannot start psql with user postgres “Could not change directory to /home/user ”

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql

I did a silly mistake. I wanted to set postgres permissions to a folder for exporting data from my database. So I set something like `sudo chmod 777 -u postgres /home/user` and then my home partition only has root permissions and nothing worked without root permissions. I solved this problem by using `sudo chown user /home/user` and then I set the permissions manually in the file manager on linux. It was very stupid, I didn't knew very much about allocating permissions to directories and users.

The Problem is now, that I can't connect to my database anymore.

```
 ~ $ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for user: 
could not change directory to "/home/user"
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I think I want to connect in a folder where the postgres user can't read.

Restarting the server with `sudo service postgresql restart` doesn't work as well.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of a relative.

The first problem was that my `/home` and `/home/user` folder didn't have the right permissions.

We set them correctly with `chmod og+rX /home /home/user`.

Then I forgot, that I created a new `PGDATA` directory in `/home/user`. And this directory had the wrong permissions. So we set them again for the user postgres with `chown postgres:postrgres -R /home/user/PGDATA`.

I decided to place the `PGDATA` directory in `/home/user` because of huge log-files that where produced during raster data queries with my PostGIS/PostgreSQL database. Sometimes I'm using Sublime Text 2 for queries and I quit them without stopping the database process and then the logfile became larger and larger and I was running out of space and nothing worked anymore.

Comment: `chmod og+X /home /home/user` seems enough in my case.

Comment: `chmod og+X /home /home/user` should work but it is also a security risk. There's a reason why the $HOME has 700 permission.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I was struggling with this problem during gvm setup. Your post solves the problem!

Comment: this solves my problem too, well defined